# Freewall.js multiple pinterest layout on one page

Tags: javascript, jquery, pinterest, freewalljs

I try to use multiple pinterest layout on one page, not nested, only several, with [`freewall.js`](http://vnjs.net/www/project/freewall/). Each `div` I want to apply the layout has a `.free-wall` class and each brick has a `.brick` class. I tried to adapt the nested layout, but does not work. All ideas will be welcome. thank you.

My script :

```js
    $(function() {
        $(".free-wall").each(function() {
        var wall = new Freewall(this);
            wall.reset({
                selector: '.brick',
                animate: true,
                cellW: 200,
                cellH: 'auto',
                onResize: function() {
                    wall.fitWidth();
                }
            });
            wall.container.find('.brick img').load(function() {
                wall.fitWidth();
            });

        });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Error was line 1, good code :

```js
 jQuery(function ($) {
        $(".free-wall").each(function() {
        var wall = new Freewall(this);
            wall.reset({
                selector: '.brick',
                animate: true,
                cellW: 200,
                cellH: 'auto',
                onResize: function() {
                    wall.fitWidth();
                }
            });
            wall.container.find('.brick img').load(function() {
                wall.fitWidth();
            });

        });

    });
```